# Can forced movement expel a creature restrained by the spell Web?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, forced-movement

Would the *thorn whip* cantrip pluck someone out of a *web* spell?

Could a *gust of wind* spell push a creature out of the sticky mass of webbing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The *web* spell does not prevent forced/involuntary movement; it merely restrains

The [*web*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/web) spell states:

> [...] Each creature that starts its turn in the webs or that enters them during its turn must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, **the creature is restrained** as long as it remains in the webs or until it breaks free [...]

Note that the [restrained](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Restrained) condition does the following things:

> - A restrained creature's speed becomes 0, and it can't benefit from any bonus to its speed.
> - Attack rolls against the creature have advantage, and the creature's attack rolls have disadvantage.
> - The creature has disadvantage on Dexterity saving throws.

No part of the condition prevents a creature from being pushed, shoved, or moved by any sort of thing. This means, grapples, shoves, or spells such as *thorn whip*, *thunderwave*, *misty step*, and *gust of wind* could all get a creature out of the webs. And since "the creature is restrained *as long as it remains in the webs* or until it breaks free" the restrained condition would then end.

This is similar to how you can shove your way out of a grapple (by shoving either the grappler or the grappled) as explained in the following questions:

- [Can you shove your way out of a grapple?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80105)
- [Does shoving a creature break its grapple on another?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133912)